# Bootstrap Thumbnail Class Not Recognized

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

Whenever I try to invoke thumbnails per the twitter documentation, I just get black dots on the screen:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="large.jpeg" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="Large">
    </a>
  </li>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I can only get something to show up using media-grid...which is strange since that's the old functionality, right?

EDIT: I still get black dots to the left of my thumbnails using media-grid, too.  How do I turn those off, and why isn't the html I wrote working?

full code:

```
<html>
 <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Walls</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="custo.css">

          <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> <!--prettyphotty-->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
          <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <br>



 <div class="container-fluid">
 <br>

 <ul class="media-grid">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="super.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="super.jpg">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="large.jpeg" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="Large">
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>



 </div><!-- .container -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> <!--initialize prettyPhoto-->
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
      });
    </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of bootstrap? Any additional details would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it yesterday from the Twitter website. version 2.3.1

Comment: It seems like the bootstrap styles are not loading. Have you checked your browser's console for errors? Are other bootstrap styles working?

Comment: Other styles are working. I just tested it.  Full code added to original post.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I thought `.thumbnails` replaced `.media-grid`? Also, if that's the link to the stylesheet you are using, it doesn't have `.thumbnail` defined. If you downloaded Bootstrap yesterday, make sure you are pointing to the downloaded file.

Comment: it's working: i had it pointed at a script that didn't exist again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet you are referencing for Bootstrap `http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css` does not have the class for `thumbnail` defined.

Once you are referencing a current version of Bootstrap, the correct structure would look something like the following (taken directly from: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails):

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Also, as of version 2...there is no `media-grid` class (taken from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/upgrading.html):

> Formerly .media-grid, now just .thumbnails, we've thoroughly extended
>   this component for more uses while maintaining overall simplicity out
>   of the box.

Comment: Okay, so I updated the head reference to  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css"> from twitters website, but it still doesn't work, even after clearing the cache. Right, I saw that they took that out, so I guess what I was seeing was just the two images I had as thumbnails put together and assuming that was media-grid.

Comment: When I pull a fresh download from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ and unzip...the path looks like /bootstap/css/bootstrap.css. I assume you downloaded the source based on the path you mentioned. The `thumbnail` class is defined around line 5548...so, it's there. Are you sure it's loading the file? Have you checked to make sure it's actually loading?

Comment: ah, i feel like an idiot. it seems so obvious now that i understand how this is working better. thank you!

Comment: we've all been there. ;) Feel free to mark as the correct answer...it helps both our reputations on SO.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap 4 uses img-fluid to resize and img-thumbnail to wrap

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="large.jpeg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
      <img data-src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="Large">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```